# How to get a list of files ignored or skipped by cloc

Tags: file, diff, cloc

If the beginning of my `cloc --vcs git` output is something like the following:

```
    1826 text files.
    1780 unique files.                                          
     384 files ignored.
```

**Question 1:** Is there a way to get a list of all the files ignored by the cloc command?

Also, if I instead run `cloc "repo_name"`, it shows a completely different number of files.

```
    2106 text files.
    1981 unique files.                                          
     346 files ignored.
```

**Question 2:** How can I get a list of which files are being skipped when running the `--vcs` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1, Ref. the `--ignored` switch in the documentation (either at https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc or via `cloc --help`):

```
--ignored=<file>      Save names of ignored files and the reason they
                       were ignored to <file>.
```

#2, `--vcs git` uses `git ls-files` to get the list of files to count.  Without this, cloc does a recursive search in the given directory.  If only a subset of files in `"repo_name"` are under git control, or if you have entries in `.gitignore`, the two methods of getting file names will differ.  This is also explained in the documentation.

```
git ls-files --other
```

will show files that aren't under git control.

Comment: Thanks @AlDanial. That totally answers the first question. The second was meant to be similar (I've updated it to clarify), how can I get a list of the skipped files?

Comment: ``git ls-files --other`` will show files that aren't under git control, is that what you mean by "skipped"?

Comment: $ /usr/bin/cloc --ignored=/tmp/ian/cloc-ignored --by-file-by-lang --vcs=git
      56 text files.
      56 unique files.                              
mkdir /tmp/ian/
Wrote /tmp/ian/cloc-ignored
       2 files ignored.